# I have a problem with my code not working properly

Tags: image-processing, autohotkey

So i wanna make a ahk that sends SPACE key when picture is found and then loops back to wait for it to reappear
Sofar ive tried to just get it to send SPACE when the picture appears but it never does send space.
I tried replacing sending space with a msgbox, and it did say the picture is found but  it never sent space...

```
image = img.png
If !FileExist(image)
 MsgBox, 48, Error, File not found.`n`n%image%
F3::
CoordMode, Pixel
ImageSearch, x, y, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %image%
If ErrorLevel
Return
Else Send, {space}
Return
```

This is the code and i will also add the img.png(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkSGA.png)
Please help :)

Comment: Works here. Is the [script for a game](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#games)?

Comment: its for an browser based game yes. The fishing system has a minigame and you have to press space when the hook is on the colored bar so i took a picture of it being ontop of there. also i want it to keep constantly running until it finds the image not only run once when f3 pressed

Comment: You have better ask in a [game forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=18).